# API design pattern for specifying different response models

Tags: api, swagger, api-design

I'm trying to rough out an api for returning article content.  It seems valuable to be able to specify whether we want the entire article, a summary, or possibly some other variation on that content.

My instinct is to add a query parameter to a GET request like `dataModel` (feel free to suggest better names).  For instance, the default may be the entire article, but `summary` may just be id, title, & description, and `list` might return id, title, author, & lastModifiedDate.

- /v0/articles/{id}
- /v0/articles/{id}?dataModel=summary
- /v0/articles/{id}?dataModel=list

However we are using Swagger for documentation and Swagger doesn't appear to support returning different objects based on query parameters ([see this](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/56)).  So I'm wondering if there are other established patterns that would be equally acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

The right solution with Swagger is to create a return type that contains common properties across all the data models.  Then you can model a `discriminator` and use the `allOf` constructs for creating the proper response type.

If you take a look at the sample definition here:

https://swaggerhub.com/api/swagger-tutorials/modeling-samples/1.0.0

You'll see how it can be done with an `Animal` return type, and `Cat` and `Dog` concrete types.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use path variables instead of URL query string for dataModel and use the following route instead

- /v0/articles/{id}
- /v0/articles/{id}/summary (returns a model with id, title & description)
- /v0/articles/{id}/list (returns a model with id, title, author, & lastModifiedDate)

Comment: This had occurred to me, but 'summary' and 'list' are just different rendering of the resource 'articles' so I'd prefer not to create new path structure for them...